# how to compare time stamp with the current date in sequelize query method

Tags: sequelize.js

How to write this query in sequelized one:

```
select COUNT(*)
    from r5.users
WHERE
    DATE_FORMAT(createdAt,'%Y%c%d')=DATE_FORMAT(current_date(),'%Y%c%d')
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do it this way,

```
Model.users.count({
where: Model.Sequelize.where(
    Model.Sequelize.fn('DATE_FORMAT',Model.Sequelize.col('createdAt'),"%Y%c%d"),
    {like:Model.Sequelize.fn('DATE_FORMAT',Model.Sequelize.fn('current_date'),"%Y%c%d")})
});
```

[`Sequelize.fn`](http://sequelize.readthedocs.io/en/v3/api/sequelize/#fnfn-args-sequelizefn) can be used to call Database functions, it expects a syntax of the form `Sequelize.fn(functionToCall, argumentsToPassToIt)`

[`Sequelize.Col`](http://sequelize.readthedocs.io/en/v3/api/sequelize/#colcol-sequelizecol) is used to refer to a particular column, say `createdAt`

[Sequelize.where](https://github.com/sequelize/sequelize/issues/2077) can be used to add functions to the columns to compare